# Get a list of all installed packages in Go

Tags: go, package-managers

How can I list all installed packages via goinstall? I need this to reinstall all packages installed on one computer to a different computer.

Comment: Note `goinstall` was only pre-Go 1.0 and hasn't existed for years; many of these answer are no longer applicible.

Comment: Yea, might want to re-accept the other answer nowadays...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a list under $GOROOT/goinstall.log
If you want to install all the packages on an different computer just copy the file across and
run,

`goinstall -a`

and goinstall will read this file and install all packages listed in it.

Comment: Upvote for both a good answer and an awesome feature I didn't know about

Comment: "feature" seems like a stretch

Answer (score 12):

Most answers here are for pre-Go 1.0 which is several years old and the answers are no longer applicable to working Go installations.

The simple answer is `go list ...` (as with other `go` sub-commands three literal periods match all packages). That will list every package on the system. See `go list -h` for other uses of this versatile command.

Dave Cheney also has a related blog article: [go list, your Swiss army knife](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/09/14/go-list-your-swiss-army-knife).

Comment: I had to quote the three dots `go list '...'` for it to work.

Comment: Not sure if this was always the case or if it was added later, but `go list all` also works in place of `...`. See `go help packages` for how to specify package names such as `all`, `...`, `std`, etc.

Comment: How to know which all external packages I have installed manually? @DaveC

Comment: for me "go list all" returns: go: warning: "all" matched no packages

Comment: @Ben I think `all` as a package name changed meaning with modules. See `go help packages`: ""all" expands to all packages found in all the GOPATH
trees. When using modules, "all" expands to all packages in
the main module and their dependencies, including dependencies
needed by tests of any of those."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a way to do it through goinstall, but there should be a list under $GOROOT/goinstall.log.