# How to list installed go packages

Tags: go

To my knowledge `go distribution` comes with some sort of `package manager`. After `go 1.4.1` installation I've run `go help` in order to find any sub-command capable of listing locally installed `go packages`, but unfortunately got none.

So how to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a list of all installed packages in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590054/get-a-list-of-all-installed-packages-in-go)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

### `goinstall` is now history

`goinstall` was replaced by `go get`. `go get` is used to manage external / 3rd party libraries (e.g. to download them, update them, install them etc).

Type `go help get` to see command line help, or check out these pages:

[**Command go**](https://golang.org/cmd/go/)

[**About the go command**](https://golang.org/doc/articles/go_command.html) (blog post)

If you want to list installed packages, you can do that with the `go list` command:

### Listing Packages

To list packages in your workspace, go to your workspace folder and run this command:

```
go list ./...
```

`./` tells to start from the current folder, `...` tells to go down recursively. Of course this works in any other folders not just in your go workspace (but usually that is what you're interested in).

### List All Packages

Executing

```
go list ...
```

in any folder lists all the packages, including packages of the standard library first followed by external libraries in your go workspace.

### Packages and their Dependencies

If you also want to see the imported packages by each package, you can try this custom format:

```
go list -f "{{.ImportPath}} {{.Imports}}" ./...
```

`-f` specifies an alternate format for the list, using the syntax of package [`template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/). The struct whose fields can be referenced can be printed by the `go help list` command.

If you want to see all the dependencies *recursively* (dependencies of imported packages recursively), you can use this custom format:

```
go list -f "{{.ImportPath}} {{.Deps}}" ./...
```

But usually this is a long list and just the single imports (`"{{.Imports}}"`) of each package is what you want.

---

Also see related question: [What's the Go (mod) equivalent of npm-outdated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55866604/whats-the-go-mod-equivalent-of-npm-outdated/55866702#55866702)

Comment: Can we list package dependencies, too?

Comment: Yes, you can do that too. Try running this command: `go list -f "{{.ImportPath}} {{.Imports}}" ./...`

Comment: Depending on your shell, you might have to quote the triple dots. `go list '...'`

Comment: I think `go get` is telling me for urls it was replaced by `go install`. I'm sure it's worth it to you to keep this answer up to date.

Answer (score 30):

Start Go documentation server:

```
godoc --http :6060
```

Visit http://localhost:6060/pkg

There will be list of all your packages.

When you install new ones they do not appear automatically. You need to restart `godoc`.

Comment: If you don't have `godoc` installed, use: `go get -u golang.org/x/tools/...`

Answer (score 2):

`go list ...` is quite useful, but there were two possible issues with it for me:

1. It will list *all* packages *including standard library packages*. There is no way to get the *explicitly* installed packages only (which is what I assume the more interesting inquiry).
2. A lot of times I need only the packages used in my projects (i.e. those listed in the respective `go.mod` files), and I don't care about other packages lying around (which may have been installed just to try them out). `go list ...` doesn't help with that.

So here's a somewhat different take. Assuming all projects are under `~/work`:

```sh
find ~/work -type f -name go.mod \
-exec sed $'/^require ($/,/^)$/!d; /^require ($/d;/^)$/d; /\\/\\/ indirect$/d; s/^\t+//g' {} \; \
| cut -d' ' -f1 \
| sort | uniq
```

A line by line explanation:

1. find all `go.mod` files
2. apply `sed` to each file to filter its content as follows (explained expression by expression):

   - extract just the `require(` ... `)` chunks
   - remove the `require(` and `)` lines, so just lines with packages remain
   - **remove all indirect packages**
   - remove leading tabs <sup>1)</sup>
3. extract just the qualified package name (drop version information)
4. remove duplicate package names

---

<sup>1)</sup> Note the sed expression argument uses [bash quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) to escape the TAB character as "\t" for readability over a literal TAB.

Comment: got heaps of `sed: 1: "/^require ($/,/^)$/!d;  ...": invalid command code /`

Comment: @star that was tue to wrong sed regex escaping in the command line. Fixed (I think).

Answer (score 0):

on *nix systems (possibly on windows with bash tools like msysgit or cmder), to see what packages I have installed, I can run:

```
history | grep "go get"
```

But thats messy output. For whatever reason I decided to see of i could clean that output up a little so i made an alias for this command:

```
history | grep 'go get' | grep -v ' history ' | sed -e $'s/go get /\\\\\ngo get /g' | grep 'go get ' | sed -e $'s/-u //g' | sed -e $'s/-v //g' | sed -e $'s/ &&//g' | grep -v '\\\n' | egrep 'get [a-z]' | sed -e $'s/go get //g' | sed -e $'s/ //g' | sort -u
```

please don't ask why I did this. Challenge maybe? Let me explain the parts

`history` the history

`grep "go get"` grep over history and only show lines where we went and got something

`grep -v " history "` and remove times when we have searched for "got get" in history

`sed -e $'s/go get /\\\\\ngo get /g'` Now we take any instances of "go get " and shove a new line in front of it. Now they're all at the beginning.

`grep "go get "` filter only lines that now start with "go get"

`sed -e $'s/-u //g'` and `sed -e $'s/-v //g'` remove flags we have searched for. You could possibly leave them in but may get duplicates when output is done.

`sed -e $'s/ &&//g'` some times we install with multiple commands using '&&' so lets remove them from the ends of the line.

`grep -v "\\\n"` my output had other lines with newlines printed I didnt need. So this got rid of them

`egrep "get [a-z]"` make sure to get properly formatted go package urls only.

`sed -e $'s/go get //g'` remove the "go get " text

`sed -e $'s/ //g'` strip any whitespace (needed to filter out duplicates)

`sort -u` now sort the remaining lines and remove duplicates.

This is totally untested on other systems. Again, I am quite sure there is a cleaner way to do this. Just thought it would be fun to try.

It would also probably be more fun to make a `go ls` command to show the actual packages you explicitly installed. But thats a lot more work. Especially since i'm only still learning Go.

Output:

```
> gols 
code.google.com/p/go.crypto/bcrypt
github.com/golang/lint/golint
github.com/kishorevaishnav/revelgen
github.com/lukehoban/go-find-references
github.com/lukehoban/go-outline
github.com/newhook/go-symbols
github.com/nsf/gocode
github.com/revel/cmd/revel
github.com/revel/revel
github.com/rogpeppe/godef
github.com/tpng/gopkgs
golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename
gopkg.in/gorp.v1
sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns
```

Comment: In bash, the history command is limited to X number of lines, where X is configured via the HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE configuration options. So, the above solution isn't likely to be reliable.

Comment: Yea thats a good point. But i figured my creation would have some kind of issues ;-)

Answer (score -1):

If you have a specific project to work on, you can just run "cat go.mod" under that project directory.

e.g

```
head  go.mod
module github.com/cilium/cilium

go 1.17

require (
        github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go v59.3.0+incompatible
        github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest v0.11.22
        github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/adal v0.9.17
        github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/azure/auth v0.5.9
        github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/to v0.4.0
```