# How to list imported module on a go source code directory

Tags: go, toolchain

Is there an `tool` or easiest way to list all imported packages on go source code directory? for example:

```
$ go list_imports a_directory/
github.com/bla/bla
github.com/foo/bar
LOCAL/module/path
```

Comment: Check out this answer: [Listing packages and their dependencies (imports)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28166550/1705598)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list installed go packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166249/how-to-list-installed-go-packages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah found the [way](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/611QEJqkDKw)..

```
go list -f '{{join .Deps "\n"}}' |  xargs go list -f '{{if not .Standard}}{{.ImportPath}}{{end}} ' | sort | uniq
```