# List of dependency URLs of a Go project

Tags: go, dependency-management

I want to get a list of tarball URLs (or similar) of all dependencies in a Go project. I tried to achieve this with 'go list dependency' but I see no possibility to get the source URL of a dependency. How can I get the URL?

Comment: If a package can be fetched with `go get`, then the URL can be determined by the import path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list installed go packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166249/how-to-list-installed-go-packages)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the current directory you get the imports by:
`go list -f '{{join .Imports "\n"}}' .`

Comment: Thank you! But I still don't get how to resolve the source URL from the import path. Take "collectd.org/api" for example. The path is derivated from the source URL but the other way around is what interests me.

Comment: For external packages it's the source-url. That's how go get downloads the packages