# Output go dependencies without fetching them

Tags: go

As part of a build process, I would like to `git clone` Go dependencies manually so I can specify `--depth 1`, among other things.

Is there a way for `go get` (or a similar tool) to output a list of Git dependencies for a Go project but *not* actually fetch them?

Comment: Not really. If you don't fetch them, how would the `go` tool tell what other packages do the _not-fetched-packages_ refer to? The packages need to be fetched in order to analyze them to tell what other packages needed (recursively).

Comment: try `go list -f {{.Deps}}`

Comment: Related: [How to list installed go packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166249/how-to-list-installed-go-packages) (it also answers how to list dependencies).