# Check for installed packages in Go

Tags: go

I need to check if some packages are installed but I need to do that using code, not `go list` tool in shell. I found a solution but it's very slow (2-3 seconds). This is my current code:

```
out, err := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "go list all").Output()
if err != nil {
    output := strings.Split(string(out), "\n")
    for _, value := range output {
        if value == "github.com/some/package" {
            // package is installed
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So basically you answered your own question. You want a faster solution? Try "tuning" the `go list` command.

To check the existence of a single package, you may pass that single package to `go list`, and if it exists, it will output it, else the output will be an error message.

For example, executing

```
go list github.com/some/package
```

If `github.com/some/package` exists, output will be:

```
github.com/some/package
```

You can also pass multiple packages to `go list`:

```
go list github.com/some/package github.com/other/package
```

And output will be:

```
github.com/some/package
github.com/other/package
```

If the passed package doesn't exist, output will be something like:

```
can't load package: package github.com/some/package: cannot find package "github.com/some/package" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/some/package (from $GOROOT)
    <GOPATH-here>/src/github.com/some/package (from $GOPATH)
```

Also note that if the package you pass does not contain `*.go` files, you get a different message:

```
can't load package: package github.com/some/package: no buildable Go source files in <GOPATH-here>/src/github.com/some/package
```

If you expect some package inside it, append the `...`:

```
go list github.com/some/package/...
```

For more options and possibilities, run `go help list`, and see related question: [How to list installed go packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166249/how-to-list-installed-go-packages/28166550#28166550)

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's 1000 times faster