# Golang - How to display modules version from inside of code

Tags: go, go-modules

I'm writing two binaries, and both of them use two libraries (we can call them libA and libB).

Each lib is in a dedicated git repo, with git-tags to declare versions.
For example, libA is at v1.0.9 and libB is v0.0.12.

Both binaries have CLI flags, and I would like to add a debug flag to display lib versions like that:

```
> ./prog -d
Used libraries:
- libA, v1.0.9
- libB, v0.0.12
```

I don't know how to do that.

The only way I see to set variable from "outside" is to use ldflags (`go build -ldflags="-X 'main.Version=v1.0.0'"` for example). But this way don't seems scalable, how to add a libC? It also imply to manage tags two times, one time for git, and one time in goreleaser.yml or makefile.

Can you help me to find a solution?

Answer (score 14):

The Go tool includes module and dependency information in the executable binary. You may use [`runtime/debug.ReadBuildInfo()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#ReadBuildInfo) to acquire it. It returns you a list of dependencies, including module path and version. Each module / dependency is described by a value of type [`debug.Module`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/#Module) which contains these info:

```
type Module struct {
    Path    string  // module path
    Version string  // module version
    Sum     string  // checksum
    Replace *Module // replaced by this module
}
```

For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "runtime/debug"

    "github.com/icza/bitio"
)

func main() {
    _ = bitio.NewReader
    bi, ok := debug.ReadBuildInfo()
    if !ok {
        log.Printf("Failed to read build info")
        return
    }

    for _, dep := range bi.Deps {
        fmt.Printf("Dep: %+v\n", dep)
    }
}
```

This outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mooLOcBNFcn)):

```
Dep: &{Path:github.com/icza/bitio Version:v1.0.0 Sum:h1:squ/m1SHyFeCA6+6Gyol1AxV9nmPPlJFT8c2vKdj3U8= Replace:<nil>}
```

Also see related question: [How to get Go detailed build logs, with all used packages in GOPATH and "go module" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890161/how-to-get-go-detailed-build-logs-with-all-used-packages-in-gopath-and-go-modu/54890460#54890460)

Comment: As far as I understand, this imply to build the binary with debug informations, I don't know what does it mean precisly.
Is there any security/confidentiality effect?

Comment: @Sébastien This only requires to build with module support, nothing else.