# How to embed a string in the compiled binary at build time?

Tags: go, build, embed

I would like to embed in the compiled binary information passed to the build process, at build time (typically a string, specifically the commit hash during my CI/CD execution).

I then would like to simply display it with `fmt.Sprintf("%v", thisEmbeddedString)`.

I was hoping for the [`embed`](https://pkg.go.dev/embed) package to be a solution, but it seems to be only for files.

Comment: Also see [Golang - How to display modules version from inside of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62009264/golang-how-to-display-modules-version-from-inside-of-code/62009359#62009359).

Comment: With Go 1.18, you can get the VCS version directly from your binary with: `go version -m file <filename>`. You need to build the binary with the full main package path, not by building individual files on the command line. (`go build .` instead of `go build main.go`)
Or from your code with 
`info, _ := debug.ReadBuildInfo();
fmt.Println(info.Settings)
`
The git commit will be under the `Key` `vcs.revision`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a variable in your code (in the example below, in `main`, it will be set in the next step)

```
var commit string
```

Add a flag to the build

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.commit=$GIT_COMMIT"
```

You can then access the variable as usual

```
log.Info().Msgf("commit → %v", commit)
```