# What's the Go (mod) equivalent of npm-outdated?

Tags: go, go-modules

I'd like to keep my `go.mod` dependencies up to date. With Node.js, I run the `npm outdated` (and later `npm update`).

What's the closest for Go mod?

Ideally, I'd see a report of outdated dependencies of my project (not all recursively). Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Listing direct and indirect dependencies

This is detailed in [Go 1.11 Modules: How to Upgrade and Downgrade Dependencies](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-upgrade-and-downgrade-dependencies) wiki:

> To view available minor and patch upgrades for all direct and indirect dependencies, run `go list -u -m all`.
>
> To upgrade to the latest version for all direct and indirect dependencies of the current module:
>
> - run `go get -u` to use the latest minor or patch releases
> - run `go get -u=patch` to use the latest patch releases

You can read more details here: [Command go: List packages or modules](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-List_packages_or_modules).

There's also a 3rd party app: https://github.com/psampaz/go-mod-outdated:

> An easy way to find outdated dependencies of your Go projects. go-mod-outdated provides a table view of the go list -u -m -json all command which lists all dependencies of a Go project and their available minor and patch updates. It also provides a way to filter indirect dependencies and dependencies without updates.

### Listing only direct dependencies

If you are not interested in indirect dependencies, we can filter them out. There is no flag to filter out indirect dependencies, but we can do that with custom output format.

> The `-f` flag specifies an alternate format for the list, using the syntax of package template.

So you may specify a format being a template document, conforming with [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/).

> When listing modules, the `-f` flag still specifies a format template applied to a Go struct, but now a `Module` struct:
>
> ```
> type Module struct {
>     Path     string       // module path
>     Version  string       // module version
>     Versions []string     // available module versions (with -versions)
>     Replace  *Module      // replaced by this module
>     Time     *time.Time   // time version was created
>     Update   *Module      // available update, if any (with -u)
>     Main     bool         // is this the main module?
>     Indirect bool         // is this module only an indirect dependency of main module?
>     Dir      string       // directory holding files for this module, if any
>     GoMod    string       // path to go.mod file for this module, if any
>     Error    *ModuleError // error loading module
> }
>
> type ModuleError struct {
>     Err string // the error itself
> }
> ```

<sup>Note: this `Module` struct is defined in an internal package of the command go: https://godoc.org/cmd/go/internal/modinfo</sup>

So for example to list direct and indirect dependencies as before, but now also append an `IAMINDIRECT` word after indirect dependencies, it could be done with:

```
go list -u -m -f '{{.}}{{if .Indirect}} IAMINDIRECT{{end}}' all
```

Negating the logic, to list direct and indirect dependencies, but this time "mark" only the direct dependencies with `IAMDIRECT`:

```
go list -u -m -f '{{.}}{{if not .Indirect}} IAMDIRECT{{end}}' all
```

And we're almost there. We now just have to filter out rows that do not contain the `IAMDIRECT` word:

```
go list -u -m -f '{{.}}{{if not .Indirect}} IAMDIRECT{{end}}' all | grep IAMDIRECT
```

#### Alternative

The above solution builds on the `grep` command. But in fact we don't need that. If the specified template results in an empty document, the line is skipped from the output.

So we can achieve the same like this:

```
go list -u -m -f '{{if not .Indirect}}{{.}}{{end}}' all
```

Basically we only call `Module.String()` (we only include a dependency) if it is not indirect. As an extra gain, this solution also works on Windows too.

### Listing only dependencies that have updates

Similarly how we filtered out indirect dependencies, this is also a "piece of cake" since the `Module` structure contains an `Update` field for packages / modules that have updates:

```
go list -u -m -f '{{if .Update}}{{.}}{{end}}' all
```

---

Also see related question: [How to list installed go packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166249/how-to-list-installed-go-packages/28166550#28166550)

Comment: the problem with that is that it lists all dependencies recursively. I only need to know the first level ones; the ones I mentioned in `go.mod`

Comment: Isn't a dependency of a dependency of your module a dependency of your module? It is indirect, but still.

Comment: @LuísSoares See edited answer for filtering out indirect dependencies.

Comment: great! what if I want to filter only the outdated? as in `npm outdated`

Comment: @LuísSoares That is also easily possible. See updated answer.

Comment: You might want `go list -u -m -f '{{if and .Update (not .Indirect)}}{{.}}{{end}}' all`, it lists all updatable direct dependencies.

Comment: The problem with `go list` is that it won't show new major versions of your dependencies. Here's a tool which can do that: https://github.com/icholy/gomajor

Answer (score 3):

Using `go list -u -m` all mentions in [icza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1705598/icza)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55866702), you can combine it with [**`psampaz/go-mod-outdated`**](https://github.com/psampaz/go-mod-outdated), from [**psampaz**](https://twitter.com/psampaz)

> `go-mod-outdated` provides a table view of the `go list -u -m -json all` command which lists all dependencies of a Go project and their available minor and patch updates.
>
> It also provides a way to filter indirect dependencies and dependencies without updates.
>
> In short it turns this:

```json
{
    "Path": "github.com/BurntSushi/locker",
    "Version": "v0.0.0-20171006230638-a6e239ea1c69",
    "Time": "2017-10-06T23:06:38Z",
    "GoMod": "/home/mojo/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/github.com/!burnt!sushi/locker/@v/v0.0.0-20171006230638-a6e239ea1c69.mod"
}
{
    "Path": "github.com/BurntSushi/toml",
    "Version": "v0.0.0-20170626110600-a368813c5e64",
    "Time": "2017-06-26T11:06:00Z",
    "Update": {
        "Path": "github.com/BurntSushi/toml",
        "Version": "v0.3.1",
        "Time": "2018-08-15T10:47:33Z"
    },
    "GoMod": "/home/mojo/go/pkg/mod/cache/download/github.com/!burnt!sushi/toml/@v/v0.0.0-20170626110600-a368813c5e64.mod"
}
```

> into this:

```
+--------------------------------+---------------+-------------+--------+------------------+
|             MODULE             | VERSION       | NEW VERSION | DIRECT | VALID TIMESTAMPS |
+--------------------------------+---------------+-------------+--------+------------------+
| github.com/BurntSushi/locker   | v0.0.0-20...  |             | true   | true             |
| github.com/BurntSushi/toml     | v0.0.0-20..   | v0.3.1      | true   | true             |
+--------------------------------+---------------+-------------+--------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with built-in `go list` is that it won't show you new major versions of a dependency. See: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40323

Here's a tool which shows outdated direct dependencies including new major versions.

https://github.com/icholy/gomajor

Example of running it on Hashicorp's Vault:

```
$ gomajor list
cloud.google.com/go: v0.65.0 [latest v0.100.2]
cloud.google.com/go/spanner: v1.5.1 [latest v1.29.0]
cloud.google.com/go/storage: v1.10.0 [latest v1.20.0]
github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest: v0.11.21 [latest v0.11.24]
github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/adal: v0.9.14 [latest v0.9.18]
github.com/SAP/go-hdb: v0.14.1 [latest v0.105.5]
github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-go/v5: v5.6.0 [latest v5.7.0]
github.com/aliyun/alibaba-cloud-sdk-go: v0.0.0-20190620160927-9418d7b0cd0f [latest v1.61.1479]
github.com/aliyun/aliyun-oss-go-sdk: v0.0.0-20190307165228-86c17b95fcd5 [latest v2.2.0+incompatible]
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go: v1.37.19 [latest v1.42.49]
github.com/cenkalti/backoff/v3: v3.0.0 [latest v4.1.2]
github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach-go: v0.0.0-20181001143604-e0a95dfd547c [latest v2.2.8]
github.com/docker/docker: v20.10.10+incompatible [latest v20.10.12+incompatible]
github.com/go-errors/errors: v1.4.1 [latest v1.4.2]
github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql: v1.5.0 [latest v1.6.0]
github.com/google/go-cmp: v0.5.6 [latest v0.5.7]
github.com/google/go-github: v17.0.0+incompatible [latest v42.0.0]
github.com/google/go-metrics-stackdriver: v0.2.0 [latest v0.4.0]
github.com/hashicorp/consul-template: v0.27.2-0.20211014231529-4ff55381f1c4 [latest v0.27.2]
github.com/hashicorp/consul/api: v1.11.0 [latest v1.12.0]
github.com/hashicorp/go-secure-stdlib/awsutil: v0.1.5 [latest v0.1.6]
github.com/hashicorp/go-secure-stdlib/mlock: v0.1.1 [latest v0.1.2]
github.com/hashicorp/go-secure-stdlib/strutil: v0.1.1 [latest v0.1.2]
github.com/hashicorp/hcl: v1.0.1-vault-3 [latest v2.11.1]
github.com/hashicorp/raft: v1.3.3 [latest v1.3.4]
github.com/hashicorp/raft-autopilot: v0.1.3 [latest v0.1.5]
github.com/hashicorp/raft-boltdb/v2: v2.0.0-20210421194847-a7e34179d62c [latest v2.2.1]
github.com/hashicorp/vault-plugin-auth-kubernetes: v0.7.1-0.20220107030939-d289258274b7 [latest v0.11.5]
github.com/hashicorp/vault-plugin-mock: v0.16.1 [latest v0.19.13]
github.com/hashicorp/vault-plugin-secrets-kv: v0.5.7-0.20220112155832-c2eb38b5f5b6 [latest v0.10.1]
github.com/hashicorp/vault/api/auth/approle: v0.1.0 [latest v0.1.1]
github.com/jefferai/jsonx: v1.0.0 [latest v1.0.1]
github.com/lib/pq: v1.10.3 [latest v1.10.4]
github.com/michaelklishin/rabbit-hole/v2: v2.11.0 [latest v2.12.0]
github.com/mitchellh/copystructure: v1.0.0 [latest v1.2.0]
github.com/mitchellh/go-testing-interface: v1.14.0 [latest v1.14.1]
github.com/mitchellh/go-wordwrap: v1.0.0 [latest v1.0.1]
github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure: v1.4.2 [latest v1.4.3]
github.com/mongodb/go-client-mongodb-atlas: v0.1.2 [latest v0.14.0]
github.com/natefinch/atomic: v0.0.0-20150920032501-a62ce929ffcc [latest v1.0.1]
github.com/ncw/swift: v1.0.47 [latest v2.0.1]
github.com/oklog/run: v1.0.0 [latest v1.1.0]
github.com/okta/okta-sdk-golang/v2: v2.9.1 [latest v2.10.1]
github.com/oracle/oci-go-sdk: v13.1.0+incompatible [latest v57.0.0]
github.com/ory/dockertest: v3.3.5+incompatible [latest v3.8.1]
github.com/ory/dockertest/v3: v3.8.0 [latest v3.8.1]
github.com/pquerna/otp: v1.2.1-0.20191009055518-468c2dd2b58d [latest v1.3.0]
github.com/prometheus/client_golang: v1.11.0 [latest v1.12.1]
github.com/prometheus/common: v0.26.0 [latest v0.32.1]
github.com/ryanuber/columnize: v2.1.0+incompatible [latest v2.1.2+incompatible]
github.com/sasha-s/go-deadlock: v0.2.0 [latest v0.3.1]
github.com/sethvargo/go-limiter: v0.7.1 [latest v0.7.2]
github.com/shirou/gopsutil: v3.21.5+incompatible [latest v3.22.1]
go.etcd.io/etcd/client/pkg/v3: v3.5.0 [latest v3.5.2]
go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v2: v2.305.0 [latest v3.5.2]
go.etcd.io/etcd/client/v3: v3.5.0 [latest v3.5.2]
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver: v1.7.3 [latest v1.8.3]
go.opentelemetry.io/otel: v0.20.0 [latest v1.3.0]
go.opentelemetry.io/otel/sdk: v0.20.0 [latest v1.3.0]
go.opentelemetry.io/otel/trace: v0.20.0 [latest v1.3.0]
go.uber.org/goleak: v1.1.11-0.20210813005559-691160354723 [latest v1.1.12]
golang.org/x/tools: v0.1.5 [latest v0.1.9]
google.golang.org/api: v0.30.0 [latest v0.68.0]
google.golang.org/grpc: v1.41.0 [latest v1.44.0]
google.golang.org/grpc/cmd/protoc-gen-go-grpc: v1.1.0 [latest v1.2.0]
gopkg.in/ory-am/dockertest.v3: v3.3.4 [latest v3.8.1]
mvdan.cc/gofumpt: v0.1.1 [latest v0.2.1]
```