# How do I list packages whose binaries are installed in $GOBIN?

Tags: go, go-modules

If I understand correctly, `go install` puts binaries in `$GOBIN` directory.

I tend to forget which packages provide which binaries in `$GOBIN` and which packages I `go install`-ed.

Is there a way to list packages that are currently `go install`-ed?

I could, obviously, do `ls $GOBIN` and that'll give me names of binaries. However, I'm looking for a way to get a list of packages with their long names, e.g. `github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk`.

**Update:** `go list ...` (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30401805/484050)) does not seem to apply to my case because this command expects me to be in a directory containing `go.mod` file. I understand that `go list` is designated for listing packages of a *project*. In my case, I need to find out all packages that are installed into `$GOBIN` of my *system*/user.

Comment: Have you tried it? What's the output when you run `go list all` in a folder outside GOPATH and without a `go.mod`? (and what's your `go version`).

Comment: @rustyx `go list all` -> `go: warning: "all" matched no packages`, `go version` -> `go version go1.16.2 linux/amd64`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For each binary in `$GOBIN`, you can use `go version -m` to show information about the version of Go and the module versions that were used to build that binary. For example, here's `go version -m ~/go/bin/goimports` for me.

```
$ go version -m ~/go/bin/goimports
/Users/jayconrod/go/bin/goimports: go1.15.2
    path    golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
    mod golang.org/x/tools  v0.0.0-20200910165216-53e29e9d1252  h1:qn28WK3EvdJOSlyZFNeWnaEX8X5GiQv+8mrw9mYrXko=
    dep golang.org/x/mod    v0.3.0  h1:RM4zey1++hCTbCVQfnWeKs9/IEsaBLA8vTkd0WVtmH4=
    dep golang.org/x/xerrors    v0.0.0-20200804184101-5ec99f83aff1  h1:go1bK/D/BFZV2I8cIQd1NKEZ+0owSTG1fDTci4IqFcE=
```

The `path` line shows the name of the `main` package that was installed. Looks like I need to update it.

```
$ go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports@latest
$ go version -m ~/go/bin/goimports
/Users/jayconrod/go/bin/goimports: go1.17rc1
    path    golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports
    mod golang.org/x/tools  v0.1.5  h1:ouewzE6p+/VEB31YYnTbEJdi8pFqKp4P4n85vwo3DHA=
    dep golang.org/x/mod    v0.4.2  h1:Gz96sIWK3OalVv/I/qNygP42zyoKp3xptRVCWRFEBvo=
    dep golang.org/x/sys    v0.0.0-20210510120138-977fb7262007  h1:gG67DSER+11cZvqIMb8S8bt0vZtiN6xWYARwirrOSfE=
    dep golang.org/x/xerrors    v0.0.0-20200804184101-5ec99f83aff1  h1:go1bK/D/BFZV2I8cIQd1NKEZ+0owSTG1fDTci4IqFcE=
```